# How to move Apply Discount Code option at Checkout?

Tags: magento2

How to move Apply Discount code option after Order Summary section of payment step. In Vendor/Magento/Sales Rule/view/front-end/layout/checkout_index_index.xml I tried modifying the item name="afterMethods" but id didn't work.

Comment: Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to remove the afterMethods component in your theme (which call the discount component): `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

The discount component itself is defined in the Magento_SalesRule module. So Once it's deleted, you can add discount the component after the order summary component in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_SalesRule/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` with something like this (code not tested, so maybe you'll need to fix it) :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>

                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```